# Gnuplot date on x axis and missing data

Tags: excel, date, charts, gnuplot, nan

I am trying to make a chart of data, which depends on time. I have this data:

```
01/1851  NaN    0.812   0.862   0.735   2.19
02/1851  NaN    1.739   1.733   1.695   1.875
03/1851  NaN    1.472   1.376   1.458   3.31
04/1851  NaN    1.847   1.775   1.828   6.06
05/1851  4.48   2.038   1.762   2.125   7.695
06/1851  10.06  0.347   0.276   0.383   5.48
07/1851  6.67   0.402   0.323   0.395   9.76
08/1851  3.21   1.57    1.469   1.421   8.62
09/1851  1.78   2.64    2.616   2.589   10.075
10/1851  3.7    1.269   1.314   1.137   4.295
11/1851  7.62   6.206   6.236   6.058   8.87
```

I need to make a chart of all this columns in one chart. Problem is, that date is monthly, and some values are NaN (not a number) which should not be ploted, but it says "all points y value undefined!" when i do this

```
set xdata time
gnuplot> set timefmt "%m/%y"
gnuplot> set xrange ["01/1851":"12/2014"]
gnuplot> set format x "%m/%y"
gnuplot> set timefmt "%m/%y"             
gnuplot> plot "milesovka.txt" u 2:3
```

Can somebody help me? I tried this even ix excel, but i doesn't take dates before 1900.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you specify `u 2:3`? You then wouldn't have a date on the x-axis.

This seems to work fine:

```
set xdata time
set timefmt "%m/%Y"
set format x "%m/%Y"
plot for [i=2:6] "milesovka.txt" u 1:i ti "Column ".i w lp
```

[image]